# Merging All Pdf Files in Directory Using iText

Tags: itext7

Hello everyone and thanks for your help in advance.  I am trying to use iText to merge all Pdf files contained within a directory.  Here is my code:

```
public class MergeFiles
{
    public MergeFiles(string targetDirectory) {
        string dest = targetDirectory +  @"\Merged.pdf";
        PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter(dest));
        PdfMerger merger = new PdfMerger(pdfDoc);            

        string[] fileEntries = Directory.GetFiles(targetDirectory);
        foreach (string fileName in fileEntries) {                

            //PdfMerger merger = new PdfMerger(pdfDoc);
            PdfDocument newDoc = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(fileName));
            merger.Merge(newDoc, 1, newDoc.GetNumberOfPages());

            newDoc.Close();                                

        };
        pdfDoc.Close();
    }
}
```

This code is resulting in the error "System.IO.IOException: The process cannot access the file 'E:\Merged.pdf' because it is being used by another process." however, I am not sure why.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: First of all, which line of your code throws that error?

Comment: are you able to get `byte[]` in response using `PdfMerger`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After these two lines:

```
string dest = targetDirectory +  @"\Merged.pdf";
PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter(dest));
```

A new (empty) file with name "Merged.pdf" is created in your target directory, with file stream opened in writing mode to write the result of the merging process.

Then, you are getting the list of file in target directory with `string[] fileEntries = Directory.GetFiles(targetDirectory);`. This array already includes your newly created `Merged.pdf` file.

Eventually the code tries to merge the resultant file into itself, which obviously fails.

To avoid this error, either collect the files to merge before creating the target document (but make sure there is no existing "Merged.pdf" file in the target directory already):

```
string[] fileEntries = Directory.GetFiles(targetDirectory);

string dest = targetDirectory +  @"\Merged.pdf";
PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter(dest));

// The rest of the code
```

Or, simply remove the target file from `fileEntries` array manually before merging the files.

Comment: Thank you so much.  I should have caught that.  I really appreciate the help.

Comment: How to get `byte[]` from `PdfWriter` using `PdfDocument`. because i am getting hard time with this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63010524/pdfdocument-to-byte-using-pdfmerger-itext7